# How to run imagemagick to batch convert only the first page of multiple PDF files to JPEG?

Tags: pdf, imagemagick, jpeg

With this command

```
convert  source.pdf[0]  output.jpeg
```

i can convert only the first page of pdf file to jpeg, but how can i do this for multiple pdf files?

Comment: One option is to write a Bash/PHP/any script around it which loops through the source files and calls ImageMagick on each of them.

Comment: Can you give me an example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Linux environment you can use `find` to run your command on any founded file.

```
find ./ -iname "*.pdf" -exec convert {}[0]  {}.jpeg \;
```

That example will look at every file with `pdf` extension in current directory.
And run `convert` command on it.

You can change `*.pdf` mask to anything. For exmaple, `document*.pdf` will found files like:

```
document1.pdf
document05.pdf
document_new.pdf
```

And output files will be:

```
document1.pdf.jpeg
document05.pdf.jpeg
document_new.pdf.jpeg
```

Hope that helps